# How to bind a checkbox to the inverse of a value?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a case when I need to bind a checkbox and the visibility of another DOM element to the inverse of a boolean property of my viewModel:

```html
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: needsReview"> Not Required 
<br>
<div id="Some related text" data-bind="visible: needsReview"> other stuff here </div>
```

```javascript
var dataFromSever = { needsReview: true };

var theModel = function (jsonData) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonData, {}, self);
}

ko.applyBindings(new theModel(dataFromSever));
```

I have more than one property like this in my actual data model, so I do not want to make multiple `ko.computed()` fields.  I'd just like to bind to `"checked: !needsReview()"` or something equally simple to maintain.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a few similar ways to handle this one.  The basic idea is that you need to create a writeable computed observable to bind the checkbox against.

You could do this in your model directly, using an extender, or by adding a function to the observable base (ko.observable.fn).

However, since you are using the mapping plugin and likely don't want to customize the way that your objects are created or add additional properties, I think that using a custom binding is the best option.  Your model really does not need to be concerned with maintaining an inverse to your property, so we can actually do this part while binding.

Here is an `inverseChecked` binding that inserts a writeable computed observable between your real observable and the binding.  Then, it simply uses the real checked binding to do its work.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.inverseChecked = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var interceptor = ko.computed({
                            read: function() {
                                return !value();
                            },
                            write: function(newValue) {
                                value(!newValue);
                            },
                            disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element
                        }); 

        var newValueAccessor = function() { return interceptor; };


        //keep a reference, so we can use in update function
        ko.utils.domData.set(element, "newValueAccessor", newValueAccessor);
        //call the real checked binding's init with the interceptor instead of our real observable
        ko.bindingHandlers.checked.init(element, newValueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        //call the real checked binding's update with our interceptor instead of our real observable
        ko.bindingHandlers.checked.update(element, ko.utils.domData.get(element, "newValueAccessor"));  
    }
};
```

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Kz4Tf/

For your `visible` binding you can do `visible: !needsReview()`

Comment: Thanks.  This looks like exactly what I need.  It just really seems like it should be simpler than this, doesn't it?  I'll see if I can't get it wired up this morning...

Comment: Cool answer, Right on. But I wonder, why not just use Radio Buttons?

Comment: I don't think that he wants to bind both.  Just wants to bind a checkbox to the inverse of what his model holds.  I just added both in the sample to show that it would respond to changes to the model or changes in the UI to the inverse.

Comment: I updated it a tiny bit, because we should really be using the same computed observable in both init/update rather than returning a new one.  Doesn't change functionality.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with KO v3. Just tried it out with no luck. It's a simple fix though, just use `ko.bindingHandlers.checked.init` instead of `update`.

Comment: I had to change update as "update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            //call the real checked binding's update with our interceptor instead of our real observable
            ko.bindingHandlers.checked.init(element, ko.utils.domData.get(element, "newValueAccessor"), allBindingsAccessor);
        }" to make it work on KO new version.

Answer (score 2):

I generally make a custom bindingHandler in KO that is the inverse of `visible`:

```
ko.bindingHandlers['invisible'] = {

    update: function(element, valueAccessor){
        var val = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        ko.bindingHandlers['visible'].update(element, function() { return !val; });            
    }
}
```

That allows you to cleanly take care of needs like you've described without cluttering your `data-bind` statements with ugly `!val()`

Comment: Thanks, but this would only take care of the `visible` binding.  It wouldn't fix the `checkbox` binding issue.

Comment: Yep - Ryan beat me to the punch on the other half of the question. Adding both of these binding handlers to your project should allow you to clean up your binding statements quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the more generic and universal way of inverting an observable / computed  value (that does not depend on any specific binding):

```js
/**
 * A small handy observable / computed function that wraps around the inverse of it's boolean value.
 * @author Nir Azuelos
 * @returns {Function}
 */
ko.observable.fn.inverse = ko.computed.fn.inverse = function() {
    return ko.pureComputed(function() { return !this(); }, this);
};
```

Usage:

```
<div data-bind="visible: myObservable.inverse()">
```

Comment: myObservable is not updated.  This is a one way binding.