# Knockout.js: Initial value of observable doesn't update RadioButton state

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Here is a **very simple** story that I fail to make it work:

We have an array of `questions`. Each question has an array of `answer`. Each answer has a `text` and `value`. Each `question` has the property `selectedAnswer` that represents the selected answer's `value`.

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/votsevfd/8/

**Implementation:**

```
<div data-bind="foreach : {data: questions}">

Question: <span data-bind="text: descr"></span>
<div data-bind="foreach: {data: answers}">
  <div>    
    <label data-bind="text: text"></label>
    <input name="something" type="radio" data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedAnswer, value: value"></input>    
  </div>
</div>
<div>
The selected answer is:<span data-bind="text: selectedAnswer"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the related `JavaScript`:

```
 var model = {
  questions: ko.observableArray(),
  };

var q1 = {
  descr: 'Do you like JS?',
  selectedAnswer: ko.observable('200'), // Initially, select No (200)
  answers: [
    {text:'Yes', value:'100'},
    {text:'No', value:'200'}
  ],
}
model.questions.push(q1);

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

**Problem:**
I want the appropriate radio button become selected according to initial value of `selectedAnswer` (in the above case, radio button `No`). But it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: It's because you're using an old knockout version. I've answered a question running in to the same problem before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38609192/3297291)

Comment: @user3297291 Thanks, but unfortunately upgrading Knockout is not an option for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a weird issue. I was able to fix it by changing the order of the `checked` and `value` bindings like this:

```
<input name="something" type="radio" data-bind="value: value, checked: $parent.selectedAnswer" />
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/votsevfd/9/)

---

There's another fix for this. If you switch to knockout's latest version, this issues goes away. So, I'm assuming they fixed it somewhere between version 2 and 3.0.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/votsevfd/10/)

(Also, you can simplify your `foreach` binding to this:`data-bind="foreach : questions"`)

**Update**:

It is indeed a bug. You can go through @user3297291's [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38606419/knockout-radio-button-binding-with-boolean/38609192#38609192) for more information regarding this.

Comment: *(repost after wrong link; thanks @JoseLuis )* I'll repeat my comment on the question here for visibility: for those curious about what has changed between version 2.x and 3.x, check out this answer I wrote: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38606419/knockout-radio-button-binding-with-boolean/38609192#38609192

Comment: @adiga How can I ever thank you. Works now like a charm. Thanks for reference too.